# Find the farest leaf on the left for every node in binary tree - solved - tree traversal in OCaml - left leaves

Tags: reference, tree, ocaml, binary-tree, imperative-programming

I managed to do this task. Answer is below. Maybe somebody will need this solution.

You have a binary tree in OCaml. Every Node has an int, left child, right child and reference to a Node.

```
type tree = Node of tree * int * tree * tree ref | Leaf;;
```

Write procedure `left_leaves : tree -> unit`
this procedure has to set reference in every node to its deepest left child.

```
         25
      /      \
     5        30
   /  \
  4    10
 /    /
2    6
```

for every node this procedure has to set reference in this node like that:

```
25 -> Node(Leaf, 2, Leaf, Leaf)
5 -> Node(Leaf, 2, Leaf, Leaf)
4 -> Node(Leaf, 2, Leaf, Leaf)
2 -> Leaf
10 -> Node(Leaf, 6, Leaf, Leaf)
6 -> Leaf
30 -> Leaf
```

How to write this procedure in Ocaml?
I was thinking about recursion.
We should go from the bottom of the tree.
At first we should change reference to Leaf. Then in next step we should change reference to left node and then recursively change every reference in node to the reference of its left child. I made procedure add which constructs BST trees for testing purposes:

```
let rec add x tree =
match tree with
|Node (l, k, r, wsk) -> 
if x <= k then
Node (add x l, k, r, wsk)
else
Node(l, k, add x r, wsk)
|Leaf -> Node (Leaf, x, Leaf, ref Leaf)

let a = Node (Leaf, 25, Leaf, ref Leaf);;

let a = add 5 a;;

let a = add 10 a;;

let a = add 4 a;;

let a = add 2 a;;

let a = add 10 a;;

let a = add 30 a;;

let a = add 26 a;;
```

This is my solution, but it doesn't work. I have no idea why.

Edit: during edition of this post i figured out how to do it. My code:

```
let rec left_leaves tree =
match tree with
|Node (l, k, r, wsk) ->
(match l with
|Node (ll, lk, lr, lwsk) ->
left_leaves l; if ll = Leaf then wsk := l else wsk := !lwsk; left_leaves r;
|Leaf -> wsk := Leaf
)
|Leaf -> ();;
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is up.
During edition of this post i managed to do it. ;D

Comment: (One reason to write up a careful description of a problem is that it often helps see the solution :-)